# numpy astype object to int conversion without raising error python 2

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

why converting numpy array of objects to int does not raise error , but convert float string wrongly?

```
>>> np.array(['1.0',1]).astype(object).astype(int)
    array([139762301422552,               1])


>>> np.__version__
   '1.14.5'
```

**Python 2.7.12**

Comment: can you give an example for the string conversion =

Comment: '1.0' is  a string in the example

Comment: Ok, with `numpy 1.15` I get an error message.

Comment: With `numpy 1.14` also:    `print(np.array(['1.0',1]).astype(object).astype(int))` results in `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.0'`

Comment: The sticky point is the conversion of the string '1.0' to int.  The object dtype intermediate doesn't make a difference,

Comment: Why are you first converting it to `object`? Perhaps if you explain exactly what you want to do, we could help you find a more elegant method by avoiding such conversions.

Comment: converting to object first because  it's an output of pandas readcsv()  [gives object]